# How to schedule local notification on some event while app is not running?

Tags: ios, notifications, background-process

I simply try to create `UILocalNotification`, schedule it and then close the app and wait for notification to appear. it works pretty fine, as I define fire time in 10 seconds since I create notification.

But how to schedule local notification, or perform some code when for example charger is plugged into device? Is it possible? Can I perform changes when app is not running but app knows about changes I register to observe?

In other words, I need to schedule local notification every time when charger is plugged in/out. No matter if app is running or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can get charger plugged state in iOS,

```
UIDeviceBatteryState batteryState = [UIDevice currentDevice].batteryState;
if (currentState == UIDeviceBatteryStateCharging || currentState == 
UIDeviceBatteryStateFull) {
// The battery is either charging, or connected to a charger and is fully charged
```

}

> But you cannot reschedule notification even app is not running.

Comment: I know I can read charging status when I am inside the app, but I need to react when app is not running. Is it possible?

Comment: No you can not run any code to reschedule any notification or some thing else any your current environment.